# Difference between executing command from command prompt and run dialog

Tags: windows, command-line, run-dialog

Is there any difference between executing a command from an open command prompt and the run dialog (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)?

What are the pros and cons of each and when should I use one over the other?

Comment: The main difference is that the console window will stay open after whatever you're doing finishes.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any advantages to use specific between them

Comment: It would be a lot easier to answer this question if you used actual words instead of ampersands and abbreviations and specify relevant information such as the OS. CMD is a key on Apple keyboards. I had to read this question thrice to finally understand it.

Comment: Well, if the window stays open you'll have a better chance to see any output that may have been generated (as well as the opportunity to do something else by typing in another command).

Comment: @Dennis: The `(Win+R)` is a major clue...

Comment: @martineau: I have no idea what's the equivalent on Mac. When I read `CMD & Run (Win+R)`, I thought about differences between OS X and Windows first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***CMD***

**Advantages**

- Run commands concurrently
- View output from programs
- Window stays open when commands complete
- Extremely flexible

**Disadvantages**

- Slower to use than run
- Unnecessary for commands with no output.

***Run***

**Advantages**

- Quickly run single commands

**Disadvantages**

- Often cannot see the output of commands
- A new window has to be opened for each new command.